# Elasticsearch multiMatchQuery with wildcard

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a requirement to search in all the fileds data with wild card in java using elaticsearch spring data in spring boot
Here is my code

```
String queryString = "362*";

            final Query searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withFilter(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(queryString))
                    .build();
           SearchHits<Measurement>  meas = elasticsearchTemplate.search(searchQuery, Measurement.class);
           
           System.out.println(meas.getTotalHits());
```

i am not able to get results with wildcard.

can someone help here.

Comment: Please explain what happens when you run this. Do you get some kind of error? Which kind? Did you try anything else?

Answer (score 0):

multi-match queries is the multi field version of the match query. And like this one, it does not support wildcards but works on analysed text. See the documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/query-dsl-match-query.html

Comment: Thank you for response. Here i need to search text in all field. that is the reason i am using multiMatchQuery. do you any eaxmple to solve this issue